# Ps4 disc drive broke

Tags: ps4

So my ps4 disc drive constantly ejects my discs and makes beeping sounds even when there isn't a disc. With fallout 4 coming out, I'd like to fix it. I've tried most things: taking out the rubber stopper, tightening the screw, rebuilding the database, unplugging it for a few hours. If anyone knows anything I might be able to try, please help me save 150 dollars.

Comment: This is an issue with the capacitive buttons. They should be cheaper to replace.